# Delete rows in MySQL using primary key index

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I am trying to delete many rows using primary key search.

e.g.

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.pid IN (SELECT pid FROM ...);
```

Here `pid` is primary key of table `t1` but it is not using index in case of delete.
The inner query is returning too many rows so the whole query is taking too much time as outer one is not using index.

How can I delete those rows faster?

Comment: "but it is not using index in case of delete" how are you sure about this? How are you checking?

Comment: If you try to delete the major part of the table, there's no performance advantage in using the index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL delete statement optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987375/mysql-delete-statement-optimization)

Comment: @AdrianNasui .. I have checked with explain statement...

Comment: The MySQL optimizer is *really* bad with sub-selects, especially when it comes to `DELETE` statements. Use a join as shown by Marco

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the subquery, but use `JOIN` instead:

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
[WHERE .....]
```

Naturally `t2` is the table you're getting pid from in your subquery; consider you can also add the `WHERE` clause to limit selected (and so deleted) pids...
Also consider that `pid` column on `t2` table should be indexed to speed up query...